# Android debugging with minifyEnabled true

Tags: android, android-studio

I am investigating an issue that is only present with minifyEnabled is set to true in Gradle.

I am using log statements to debug but the issue is apparently pretty deep. Is there anything I can do to have minifyEnabled set to true, but still be able to use the Android Studio debugger?

I know the answer is probably 'no', but I wanted to ask anyway.

In short: is it possible to run the Android Studio debugger with `minifyEnabled` set to `true`?

Comment: Add some code and show what you've done to try and solve the problem

Comment: So, this isn't really a code specific question. It's more along the lines of: is it possible to run the debugger with minifyEnabled set to true

Comment: It looks like you've summed up your question nicely there. Maybe consider adding what the *behavior* you are encountering is, whenever you try to debug. NOTE: 'It doesn't work' is not a sufficient explanation of any problem.

Comment: The behavior is that I can't run the debugger with minifyEnabled. Android studio never enters the code or hits any of the breakpoints.

Comment: You have essentially said 'it doesn't work'... Are there any windows that pop-up, error messages, etc.

Comment: Look, I am trying my best here. Clearly, you don't have knowledge with the specific question that I am asking. And that's OK. Maybe if you don't understand statements as axiomatic as "breakpoints don't get hit", you can say to yourself "hmm...doesn't seem like something I am familiar with. I will pass". Also, if I was getting error messages, I would have mentioned that. Just like most developers would.

Comment: You ever find a solution to this? Still trying to myself...

Comment: No, it can't be done (as far as I know).

Comment: Similar problem here. Although I've selected **debug** as the build variant and minifyEnabled is true only in **release** section of my build.gradle, I can not debug until I've changed it to false...

Comment: @MarcDiNino were you able to resolve the issue ? I am facing similar issue where my debug build is working just fine but not in PROD when minifyenabled is set to true.

Comment: It can't be done (yet).

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with `minifyenabled true` and the solution is to fill the code with lots of Logs and debug through them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No ..but you should avoid using it on debug build. it will slow down your application .it is usefull when you release the APK for testing purposes but before that, Make you aware of using MinifyEnabled. follow this link. it is used for enable the code shrinking.(Unused codes will be shrinked).

See [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html).

Answer (score 29):

It is already possible to debug minified applications. 
First, edit your `proguard-rules.pro` and add lines:

```
-dontobfuscate
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

Also, make sure to comment out this line:

```
# -renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
```

Then, edit your application `build.gradle` file and define your debug build type in the following way:

```
debug {
    minifyEnabled true
    useProguard false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

All of these changes are necessary(if you skip `keepattributes` and `renamesourcefileattribute`, then debugging will work, but logging will still point to wrong place in the code)

Then, run the application with debugger.

The logging will now point you exactly to the proper place in the code. Also, if there are any breakpoints set, these will be executed properly. Android Studio will allow you to investigate variables, check for conditions and evaluate the code.

Remember to remove the changes in the `proguard-rules.pro` file before you build the release. You can also define debug and release settings in separate proguard files.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Yes, really this should be accepted answer. Worked like a charm.

Comment: If I add that `useProguard false` line I get cryptic gradle errors: `Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: build_e2affs1uiae8d7dqn7brhtd9x.android() ...` ??

Comment: commenting -renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile works for me. Thanks +1

Comment: Doesn't work for me, same issue as @RobN

Answer (score 2):

Modified answer of @KrzysztofSroga https://stackoverflow.com/a/61705347/2425851

Create new `stage` `buildType` at `buildTypes`:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            debuggable false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        stage {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard false
            debuggable true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-rules-stage.pro'
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true     
        }
    }
```

Create near `proguard-rules.pro` new file `proguard-rules-stage.pro`

**proguard-rules-stage.pro:**

```
-dontobfuscate
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

Now you may switch between debuggable build types at window `Build Variants`

Answer (score 0):

just add this these tow lines in ProguardFile :

```
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
```

because the problem when you use

```
{ }.getType()
```

when you deserialize JSON string to ArrayList